# tell me about sql query two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

this my data

```
       day  room    ids section idt term    years   
        1   1207    400 101 1   te00    1   2557    
        1   1207    400 102 1   te00    1   2557    
        1   1207    400 103 1   te00    1   2557    
        1   1207    400 101 2   te00    1   2557
        1   1207    400 102 2   te00    1   2557
        1   1207    400 103 2   te00    1   2557
```

this my  table:tbtables

tbstudent

```
            idstd          namestd        ids           section  term    years  
            55001          aa            400 101        1         1      2557   
            55001          aa            400 102        1         1      2557
            55001          aa            400 103        1         1      2557
            55002          ab            400 101        2         1      2557
            55002          ab            400 102        2         1      2557
            55002          ab            400 103        2         1      2557
            55003          ac            400 101        1         1      2557
            55003          ac            400 102        1         1      2557
            55003          ac            400 103        1         1      2557
```

this my code:

```
    SELECT        idstd, namestd
    FROM            tbstudent
    enter code here
    WHERE        (ids =
    (SELECT        ids
                               FROM            tbtables
                               WHERE        (ids = @ids) AND (section = @section)))
```

**    i input ids=400 101 and section=2

what happened i don't understand please tell me
    output**

```
    idstd          namestd
     55001         aa
     55002         ab
     55003         ac

why :(
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use as

```
SELECT        idstd, namestd
    FROM            tbstudent
    WHERE        (ids = @ids) AND (section = @section)
```

It will return only

> idstd | namestd
>
> 55002   |         ab

Why you need   inner join with `tbltable`

In your query it is `tbltable`  returning `400 101`  and `tblstudent` having 3 records with same id.

Comment: tbtables send value from ids and section to tbstudent
select id,name from tbstudent in ids,section

Answer (score 1):

with the nested query

```
SELECT        ids
FROM            tbtables
WHERE        (ids = @ids) AND (section = @section)
```

you have selected the ids that match the search, result -> 400 101

with the other query

```
SELECT        idstd, namestd
FROM            tbstudent
WHERE        (ids = ...
```

you select idstd, namestd where ids = previus result -> 400 101,

then your result